# Merging master repo with an older modified forked copy

Tags: git, github

I got myself in a sticky situation here. I am trying to bring the changes from a master repo which has been modified by others into a forked copy which is slightly behind but this forked copy has commits not found in the master repo.

So basically: Master (ahead) --> Fork (older, modified)

Whenever, I follow the github instructions provided in the git merge web UI, the commit history is lost. It makes it seem like I made all the commits into the forked copy. Can we retain the original authors or is this how git works?

Comment: Also. I am facing merge conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch all the upstream changes from the original repository, you have to make sure that the upstream ist set correctly to the original repository to fetch the changes with

```
git remote add original https://github.com/{author}/{repo}.git
```

You can than load all the original changes with `git fetch original` and
`git rebase original/master` to get all these changes into your forked repository.